# Grails-3.1.11 application running issue

Tags: grails

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -classpath E:\Users\viswanadha-k\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app
|Running application...
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor: method ()V not found
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.WebApplicationContextServletContextAwareProcessor.(WebApplicationContextServletContextAwareProcessor.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:517)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at merck.serono.sasp.epc.ecko.Application.main(Application.groovy:9)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':merck-serono-sasp-epc-ecko:bootRun'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error |
  Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1

Please any one provide the sollution

Comment: which version of Jdk your using ?

Comment: can you show  this build.gradle file ?